# Key-Value Observing and RoboVM

Tags: java, ios, robovm

I want to define an observer in a roboVM project. To do so I use the key value observer functionality. Here is my code:

```
    button.setTitle("Click me!", UIControlState.Normal);

    button.addOnTouchUpInsideListener(new UIControl.OnTouchUpInsideListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTouchUpInside(UIControl control, UIEvent event) {
            button.setTitle("Click #" + (++clickCount), UIControlState.Normal);
        }
    });

    Foundation.log("title: " + button.getKeyValueCoder().getValue("title"));

    button.addKeyValueObserver("title", new NSKeyValueObserver() {
        @Override
        public void observeValue(String keyPath, NSObject object, NSKeyValueChangeInfo change) {
            Foundation.log("2");
        }
    });
```

this will log the following line:
title: null

When clicking the button the title will be changed on screen but the observer will never be called. Any idea what is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to observe something which isn't observable. There's no `title` property on `UIButton`. There is however a `titleLabel` property which is a `UILabel` which has a `text` property that you can observe:

```
Foundation.log("titleLabel.text: " + button.getKeyValueCoder().getValue("titleLabel.text"));

button.addKeyValueObserver("titleLabel.text", new NSKeyValueObserver() {
    @Override
    public void observeValue(String keyPath, NSObject object, NSKeyValueChangeInfo change) {
        Foundation.log(keyPath + " " + object + " " + change);
    }
});
```